# How to run-length encode without groupby

Tags: python

I have input in sorted order such as:

```
L = [5,5,7,7,7,7,9,10,12,14]
```

and I want to count the number of times each number occurs. This gives output:

```
[2,4,1,1,1,1]
```

I don't need to store the original values. I also don't want to use groupby. This is because I will run my code with [pypy](https://pypy.org/) which speeds up simple loops best.

I can do it inefficiently using:

```
S = set(L)
[L.count(item) for item in S]
```

Is there a simple linear time solution maybe just with one for loop?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are indeed looking for *run-length counts* and not *total counts*? In other words should `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]` produce `[2, 2, 2]` or `[4, 2]`?

Comment: @CoryKramer The input is sorted so they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) was created for:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter([5,5,7,7,7,7,9,10,12,14])
>>> [counts[i] for i in sorted(counts.keys())]
[2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Alternatively, if you want to optimize for memory usage, here's a function that takes any iterable, even a generator that sources numbers from a file:

```
def run_lengths(lst):
    previous_val = None
    num_vals = 0 
    for i in lst:
        if previous_val is None:
            previous_val = i 
        if i == previous_val:
            num_vals += 1
            continue
        yield num_vals
        previous_val = i 
        num_vals = 1 
    if num_vals:
        yield num_vals

print(list(run_lengths([5,5,7,7,7,7,9,10,12,14])))  # Returns [1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1]

def file_generator(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for l in f:
            yield int(l.strip())

 print(list(run_lengths(file_generator('my/huge/file.dat'))))
```

Comment: This is not correct. This will count *total occurances* which is different from *run length* which the items must be contiguous

Comment: @CoryKramer The input is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a little function to be efficient if you have really large data.

```
L1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9]  
L2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]

def countr(lst):
    res = []
    count = 1

    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        if lst[i] == lst[i + 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            res.append(count)
            count = 1

    res.append(count)
    return res

countr(L1)
# [4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1]

countr(L2)
# [4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8]
```

Comment: Rewritten answer, I guess this has bigO(n) with one for loop. @PM2Ring

Comment: That's better! It'd be interesting to see how it compares speed wise to a solution that uses zip to iterate over a pair of lists, rather than indexing. For small data that's easy enough by doing eg  `zip(L, L[1:])` but that's not so good for big data, since it copies `L`. But I guess you could do it with `islice`.

Comment: This does require, though, that the entire list can be held in memory. You could rewrite `countr` to accept a generator that loads from e.g. a file.